# document.cookie not working in Firefox 16.0.2

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to store the cookie and retrieve it but it works good in all other browsers eve in IE but its not working in FF

My Code to set cookie is

```
var startTime = e.timeStamp;
var setStartCookie = "startTime="+startTime;
document.cookie=setStartCookie;
```

and when i access the cookie using

```
$_COOKIE['startTime']
```

Please help me ASAP... 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided above worked for me on Firefox 16. Please ensure that the browser is configured to accept cookies.

Comment: How to check weather the cookie is set or not and how to enable cookie

Comment: For checking if the cookie is set, right-click on the page, select 'View Page Info' and on the 'security' tab select 'show cookies'. For enabling cookies follow the instructions on [this](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-and-disable-cookies-website-preferences) page.